# Why the TextView gets truncated in a TableView and doesn´t fit the width of his TableRow parent?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, tablerow

I've this xml for a custom row in a ListView cell, but the TextView 'commentTextView' is getting wrapped, and doesn't respect his father width.

```
    <!-- top left bend -->
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <ImageView style="@style/FormImageViewTopLeftBendStyle"
            android:contentDescription="@string/none" 
        />   
    </TableRow>
    <!-- top left bend -->

    <!-- Photo & Comment -->

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <!-- User Photo  -->

         <ImageButton style="@style/FormBasicStyle"
             android:id="@+id/userImage"
             android:background="@drawable/ic_default_user"
             android:contentDescription="@string/user_photo_description" 
             />

        <!-- User, Comment & Time -->

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/commentTextView"
            style="@style/FormTextViewStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:background="@color/yellow"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:text="@string/the_text_commented"   
         />        
   </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image: Problem With TextView]

What I have to do to make a multiline TextView that doesn´t gets wrapped?

Comment: Change width to match_parent or set **maxLines** for TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

And add a layout weight element with weight other than 0

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

It's worked for me. But i couldn't find what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

set layout_width to match_parent

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: I´ve done that, but the problem is not solved... I don't know if this is an Android Bug or something...

Comment: it's not a bug. The problem is not in width it's in height

Comment: your table row has height set to wrap_content and text_view to match_parent. Try changing height to wrap_content as well

Comment: @Jimmy If you want to multiLine then set maxLines for it and also change height to wrap_content

Comment: The maxLine attribute doesn´t solve the problem, and adds another because I don't know how many lines will have the TextView.

Comment: If that problem then you should put your TextView in Scrollview with wrap_content height.